# Xcode 6.1(6A1052d) NSURL strange behavior on different Macs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

i can't figure out why xcode 6.1(6A1052d) on Mac Pro treat NSURL different From Xcode 6.1(6A3117) on MacBook Pro. Example

MacPro:

```
    if ( [[pb types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType] ) {

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pb];
            NSLog(@"fileURL Drop %@", fileURL);

    }
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
```

OUTPUT: fileURL Drop file:///.file/id=6571367.27666129

MacBook Pro :

```
    if ( [[pb types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType] ) {

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pb];
            NSLog(@"fileURL Drop %@", fileURL);

    }
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
```

OUTPUT: fileURL Drop file:///Users/su.../Desktop/Hardsoul%20feat.%20Candy%20Dulfer%20-%20Lust%20For%20Life%20(Hardsoul%20Mix).mp3...

As you can see the same method return different URL one as normal URL and other as file ID. So please need an help to understanding what happen. Normally i work in the same project with two different mac... one at once.

Answer (score 1):

// i was using Apple Docu Sample :  extract filename from nsurl
// changed to this

```
    if ([[[sender draggingPasteboard] types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType])
    {
        NSArray *files = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        pathOfDraggedImage = [files objectAtIndex:0];
        pathOfDraggedImage =    [pathOfDraggedImage lastPathComponent];

        pathOfDraggedImage = [pathOfDraggedImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"_"];

        if ([pathOfDraggedImage length] > 70) {
            // only take 70 characters
            pathOfDraggedImage =  [pathOfDraggedImage substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 70)];
        }
    }
```